# How do I append List<string> in the following recursive function

Tags: c#, list

```
 class FileSetGenerator
     {
         public static void FileSetGen(string[] arg, string path, string pattern, oout List<string> files)
         {
        int count = 0;
        files = new List<string>();
        if(arg.Contains("/R"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Called");
            files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(path, pattern));
            count++;
            //List<string> dummy = new List<string>();
            foreach (string file in files)
                Console.WriteLine(file);
            string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
            foreach (string dir in dirs)
                FileSetGen(arg, dir, pattern, out files);

        }
        else
            files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(path, pattern));
    }
}
```

I am trying to get all the files rooted at a specified directory(path) using this recursive call. So particularly i want to fill the List<> structure with all the files present in the pwd and it's sub-directories. But everytime the recursive function is called, the List<> structure gets hthe files of the sub-directory and the previous files gets over-written. Is there any way by which I can append the new data with each execution of the recursive call?
I am coding in c#.

Comment: Is there a reason you're avoiding the AllDirectories option of the GetFiles method?  If you're using .NET 4.0 you can use EnumerateFiles as well I believe for better performance.

Comment: Heyy, thanks! This would work perfectly fine with me. Wow, .NET is so flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass initialized list to the first call of the function.

But seems like you are searching for all files with a pattern, in directory. 
You can use [`Directory.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx) overload that accepts [SearchOption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143448.aspx), which you can specify as AllDirectories to get files in all subfolders.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, use `ref` instead of `out` for the last parameter of your function and do not recreate it inside the function. Instead create the list once in the caller function and send it as ref parameter to this function. `Directory.GetFiles()` however already does what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: He doesn't need `ref` either, really.